# Android AudioRecord delay when using bytes, not when using and shorts

Tags: android, xamarin, audiorecord

I'm developing an Xamarin Android application where video and audio are recorded with some playing music. I need to merge all these streams together.

I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing when recording audio using byte[] (or ByteBuffer which I also tried out) in the audioRecord.read() function. The output WAV file seems right (is clearly playable at a 44100Hz sample rate), but a delay appears after a couple of seconds and tends to get bigger and bigger.

When using shorts, I don't have any delay in the MIC recorded audio. The big issue using shorts is that no mather what I do, I can't have a sample rate higher then 8000hz (but this isn't the current issue although if someone knows how to fix it I'll take it :) )

The final merged file is an mp4 with AAC audio, merged using ffmpeg, but I don't think this is the issue.

Could it be related to 8000Hz (using short) and 44100Hz (using byte) ? Or I'm a adding something when using byte[] since I don't check how many bytes are read ?

Here are the parts involved in the issue:

```
//output file initialization
mDataOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new Java.IO.File(mRawFilePath));

public void Run()
{

...

short[] shortBuf = new short[bufferSize / 2];
//byte[] byteBuf = new byte[bufferSize];

while(isRecording) {
    //using shorts
    audioRecorder.Read(shortBuf, 0, shortBuf.Length);
    WriteShortsToFile(buf);

    //using byte[]
    //audioRecorder.Read(byteBuf, 0, byteBuf.Length);
    //WriteBytesToFile(buf);    
}

...

}

public void WriteShortsToFile(short[] shorts)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < shorts.Length; i++)
    {
        mDataOutputStream.WriteByte(shorts[i] & 0xFF);
        mDataOutputStream.WriteByte((shorts[i] >> 8) & 0xFF);
    }
}

public void WriteBytesToFile(byte[] buf)
{
    mDataOutputStream.Write(buf);
}
```

Comment: it should be WriteShortsToFile(shortBuf) - In my code it's correct by I adapted the variable name for this question

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working as it should.

I changed the allocation size of the short array to bufferSize.